# Is it possible in some ring $1=0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider a ring $R$ and the ideal $I$ in $R$ and the quotient ring $R/I$. With defining $(r+I)(s+I)=(rs+I)$ for any $r,s \in R$, I concluded that $0=I$ and $1=I$ in $R/I$ thus $0=1$ in $R/I$ :

$$I+(r+I)=r+(I+I)=r+I \implies I=0$$ and $$(I)(r+I)=(0+I)(r+I)=0r+I=I \implies I=1.$$

1- Is that possible that identity of two operations $\times$ and $+$ in a ring be the same?

2- Am I right with the calculations above?

Comment: Do a Google search for the trivial ring.

Comment: Your conclusion that $I=1$ is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The only ring in which $0=1$ is the trivial ring,  the ring with 1 element.   Proof:  Let $x\in R$.   Then $1x=x=0x=(0+0)x=0x+0x$,  hence $0x=0=1x=x$,  hence all $x\in R$, $x=0$.
Some authors don't allow this to be a ring, but most do.

Answer (score 0):

There's the trivial ring, which has one element. In that case $0=1$.

Comment: Everybody has mentioned the trivial group. As in the question 2 and the calculations in the OP, in the quotient ring also 1=0. Am I right? Thank you.