# Question on a ring result

Tags: ring-theory

If R is a ring and a, b, c are elements of R, then does b=c always imply ab=ac, or do I need to prove it using ring axioms?

Comment: This is always true because your multiplication is a well defined map.

Comment: You *can* prove it. Whether or not you *need* to prove it depends on  what was requested (in the homework or exam).

Comment: If $\,f(x,y)\,$ is *any* function from $R^{\large 2}\to R$ then $\,b = c\,\Rightarrow\, f(a,b) = f(a,c).\,$ OP is the special case when $f$ is the ring multiplication operation.

Comment: I agree with @DietrichBurde however unless this is the very first weeks of a very basic course it's unlikely you need to prove such a thing. But you should know why it is true.

Comment: To clarify, I am not asked to prove this, but I merely need to use this to prove another result (namely that, if R is a ring with identity, and ''0'' = ''1'', then R has only 1 element). Thing is, it is my first time doing rings, so I am super careful with what I consider a ''known result'' and I think I must prove everything I use, even if it is basic algebra.

Comment: @DietrichBurde there was no typo, the implication i ask about is indeed b = c => ab = ac

Comment: In this case have a look at the (super careful) answer by Alan on your question about the trivial ring [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1520132/is-it-possible-in-some-ring-1-0).